# how to use facebook comments plugin into facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-fbml, facebook-page

We have a Face book page.We add a custom FBML tab.Now we want to add Comment Face book plugin.I tried to add an script what i got from [Face book Social Plug in](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments).The code is

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script 
<src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=178089302222317&amp;amp;xfbml=1"></script><fb:comments numposts="10" width="425" 
publish_feed="true"></fb:comments>
```

After that i put this script to custom FBML page but its not reflecting any thing please suggest to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<fb:comments xid="some_unique_id_doesnt_matter_what" canpost="true" candelete="false" publish_feed="true" numposts="10" returnurl="http://facebook.com/YOURPAGE">

<fb:title>Headline</fb:title>
</fb:comments>
```

this is what you are looking for.. your code doesnt work in FBML, yours is XFBML

```
<fb:title>
```

is optional

Comment: Thanks it works but in case you want to post with my profile option it is not working.Please check your code.

Answer (score 3):

You should start over and not use FBML but use an iframe instead.

You are trying to create an app on a page tab. To do this take a look at the FB dev site and it shows you how to get started with an iframe based app and then how to get that to work on a page tab.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/#tabs

Once you move to iframes you can use all of the social plug-ins and other advanced features like the Graph API.